# add custom section in admin sales order view in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, admin-panel

I am stuck in custom code. Actually I want to add custom information section on sales order view page in admin like Account Information', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address'.
But I don't want to edit any core file like phtml, xml etc.

Here I am attaching screen-shot for more clear to me.

[image]

Please help me to get resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

By default there are only a 2 options, to add it via plain xml.

before the content, and after the content.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="test-1" template="test/template.phtml" after="sales_order_edit"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="test-2" template="test/template.phtml" before="sales_order_edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

but those templates will be shown in all tabs.

to insert into several parts, you have to add your template like:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
        <block type="core/template" name="test-1" template="test/template.phtml" after="sales_order_edit"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="test-2" template="test/template.phtml" before="sales_order_edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Watch out for the changed reference name.

In the corresponding template `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml` you can place your block everywhere you want

```
[...]
<div id="order-messages">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_messages') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('test-1') ?>
[...]
```

the main problem is, that the sales_order_view is kinda hard coded, so it'll keep the structure.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This article provides a step by step guide of how to add new block in sales orde view page: http://www.webspeaks.in/2015/12/magento-add-custom-block-in-admin-sales-order-page.html

Answer (score 1):

**techguy4web**, you can follow the below link. It will resolve your requirement.
[http://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141016015913/http://sohelrana09.wordpress.com:80/2011/06/24/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento/)

Comment: thanks Supravat! it's a good solution but not that I am seeking for. I want to set my custom block similar like using setChidBlock in xml directly.